# How to rename libc.a back

Tags: command-line-interface, aix, rename, mv

I am working on AIX 6.1 and inadvertently renamed `/usr/lib/libc.a` to `usr/lib/libc.a_`  Just as I renamed I realized my stupid mistake. Almost all of the commands `mv`, `cp`, `ftp` etc ( except `cd` ) have stopped working.

How shall I rename by `libc.a` back. Without it, the system hardly functions sanely :(

Comment: Try every possible way to fix it and be imaginative. You can do it with `dd`, `cat`, `ln`, and probably a dozen other commands. Check your list of shell internals (`read -N`?). Are any servers already running that could be made to do it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Actually I was running on a virtualized environment of AIX. I mean I was running on one of the several partitions on a single server

Comment: Got Busybox? That might do it.

Comment: I am not proficient on AIX but does not a `.a` suffix mean a _static_ library? Is it possible that you have messed up the shared libc file too? BTW, `cd` is a command embedded to the shell

Answer (score 3):

Most of the binaries depend/use on the `libc` library. To find out, you can use `ldd /path/to/binary`
It seems that you need to boot another image or live CD. Then, you can mount the relevant partition (`/usr` if it is separated or `/`) and rename the file.

Comment: [the ldd utility is not a part of the normal AIX OS install](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21162912) ...

Answer (score 2):

Just posting this in case someone else searches for this issue.

Since at least AIX 5.3 IBM has provided the recovery shell `recsh` just for this issue.

Check [IBM Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/recsh.htm).

Example of use: `recsh; cp -p  libc.a.new /usr/lib/libc.a; exit`

Answer (score 1):

I guess `ln` is out of question, too?

```
ln -s usr/lib/libc.a_ usr/lib/libc.a
```

Or Perl?

```
perl -e 'symlink("usr/lib/libc.a_","usr/lib/libc.a");'
```

or

```
perl -MFile::Copy -e 'copy("usr/lib/libc.a_","usr/lib/libc.a");'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `while read -r x; do echo $x >> libc.a; done < libc.a_` (This assumes a Bourne style shell).

If it fails and you are lucky enough that `ed` or `sed` are statically linked try:

`sed libc.a_ > libc.a`

or

```
ed libc.a_
w libc.a
q
```

also `dd if=libc.a_ of=libc.a`

Answer (score 0):

Boot from rescue disk, mount filesystem, do rename.